# Display selected Text

Tags: android

Suppose I have a TextView with the text "Select text in your web browser and click the Spreed". If I select the first couple of words ("Select text") and click the OK button, just those two selected words should be displayed in the next activity. How would I go about doing this in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from here : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

You could provide data between activities using intents and bundle.